# Route not found in node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am currently learning the MEAN stack by working my way through [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/). I have set up the node server and gotten mongodb successfully running however when i go to test the database via:

```
curl --data 'title=test&link=http://test.com' http://localhost:3000/posts
```

it gives me a 404 error. How ever if i just run curl on the address it sends back an empty container.

Currently my code looks like the following:

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var users = require('./routes/users');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Posts');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers
...
module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express'
    });
});

router.get('/Posts', function(req, res, next) {
    Post.find(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(posts);
    });
});

router.post('/Comments', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);

    post.save(function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.json(post);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I feel like I have a fairly good grasp of javascript however i am stumped with why this isnt working. Thanks for the help, this is the first problem ive been completely stumped with

Comment: Your route is `Posts` not `posts` maybe that's it.

Comment: wow i completely missed that. Guess i need to look at things more closely next time. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Happens to everyone :)