# Node/Express external API call from internal endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

In my node/Express app, I want to make a request to an external API using a secret API key. Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398903/node-process-env-variables-empty) I asked, I decided to build an internal endpoint and make a request from that endpoint (where I have access to my server-side ENV variables) to the external API.

So I created a wrapper class that would interact with the API like so:

```
new FreeImages('search-keyword').fetch( callback(apiResponse) )
```

And I created an internal endpoint to grab that response and return it as requested internally. So my endpoint should look like this:

```
router.get '/images', (req, res, next) ->
  new FreeImages('nature').fetch (images) ->
    res.json(images)
```

But that doesn't work, and neither does this:

```
router.get '/images', (req, res, next) ->
  new FreeImages('nature').fetch (images) ->
    res.json({ unrelated: 'json' })
```

But this does:

```
router.get '/images', (req, res, next) ->
  res.json({ unrelated: 'json' })
```

Which leads me to believe (since my FreeImages class has worked in other contexts) that the issue is asynchrony -- the internal endpoint tries to return before receiving the data to return.

Am I right about what's wrong here? How can I get around it and route my API call through an internal endpoint that obscures my key?

**EDIT**

Here's the FreeImages class:

```
$ = require('jquery')
_ = require('lodash')

class FreeImages

  constructor: (@search) ->

  fetch: (callback) ->
    $.ajax
      crossDomain: true
      type: 'GET'
      url: @_dataUrl()
      dataType: 'jsonp'
      jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback'
      success: (result) ->
        images = _.reduce(result.sources, ((array, source) ->
          array.concat source.result
        ), [])

        callback images
      error: (result) ->
        console.log 'Something went wrong fetching images.'
        false
    true

  _dataUrl: ->
    "http://freeimages.pictures/api/user/#{ process.env.FREE_IMAGES_API_KEY }/?keyword=#{ @search }&format=jsonp"

module.exports = FreeImages
```

I don't think it's at fault, because I used it previously directly from the front-end (with a hard-coded API key), and it worked fine. The `console.log` in the error case doesn't seem to get hit, either. And the server shows no error messaging that's particularly useful:

```
GET /images 500 27.680 ms - 2566
```

Also, if I `console.log` above and below the `FreeImages.fetch` line, the former, but not the latter, is printed to the server logs. So it seems to not be entering the callback at all.

**EDIT2**

If I keep console logging, it gets right up to the `$.ajax` call in `FreeImages`, but not beyond it. Not sure what's going wrong, as the URL looks right there, and the code is identical to what was working earlier.

Comment: It says in your previous question that you receive an error 500 ; is this from the API call or from your front-end perspective ? Because if the API is giving you a 500 error than there's not much you can do. 5xx errors are server side errors. More about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Could you show us some code from your FreeImages class, and give us more detail about the error please.

Comment: Added the class above.

Comment: I must say I am not quite familiar with Coffee Script or jQuery on Node's server side. When I need to make calls to an API I use this Node module : [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest). Your routing code looks correct to me, I would look into your `FreeImages` class. Maybe try using the module I just mentioned ? I feel like the problem comes from the way you make the AJAX call.